# Can't handle 1.9.x error when trying to install linecache with Ruby 2.1.1

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, linecache

I am trying to install linecache with RVM on Ruby 2.1.1.

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]
```

I run bundle install

```
$ bundle install
```

It blows saying it isn't compatible with 1.9.x when I run bundle install:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/g/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
Can't handle 1.9.x yet
*** extconf.rb failed ***

Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries
and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/g/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/g/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/linecache-0.46 
for inspection.

Results logged to /home/g/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0
/linecache-0.46/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing linecache (0.46), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install linecache -v '0.46'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Any ideas whats happening here?

Comment: I ran in a similar problem when upgrading to Ruby 2.3 with RubyMine EAP. Did you have any luck in resolving this?

Answer (score 1):

Linecache hasn't been updated in 3 years, the last update was bringing it up to version 1.9.3. Unless you're pulling it from someone else's fork, since you're using 2.1.1 the gem won't work. Most likely the error message hasn't been updated so it just tells you it's invalid for 1.9.x since it doesn't know about any newer versions.

Comment: Jetbrains idea 12 v129.1521 tried to install it automatically. Failed from the IDE, so I trying from the CL, also fails, not sure why idea is making me install something thats incompatible with my setup... and I know its worked in past installs of idea.

Comment: @Geremy like I said it won't work for your 2.1.2 Ruby installation since it hasn't been updated for anything since 1.9.3. JetBrains is most likely simply attempting to find the latest Linecache and attempting to install it. If you're going to try installing it from the command line you'll have to find a different version (probably someone else's fork) that will work with your version of ruby.